# Compile Time Template restriction C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

Basically I have 4 classes:

- OverVoid
- Meta: that inherits OverVoid
- Physical: which has nothing to do with the above
- Move: a templated class

I want move's template to accept objects of only OverVoid type i.e. OverVoid and Meta.

```
class OverVoid{
public:

    virtual ~OverVoid(){
    };
};

class Meta: public OverVoid{

};

class Physical{
public:
};

template<typename _Ty>
class Move{

};
```

I want an error to be trown at compile time,
I know there is a way with boost but I cannot use Boost (dev issues with my company)

any ideas?

Comment: Maybe put a tag in the OverVoid class and then do a static assert in the template

Comment: What is "Container"? It's not in your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the template definition for classes not of type `OverVoid`

```
template<typename _Ty, 
         class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<OverVoid, _Ty>::value>::type>
class Move{

};
```

You then get an error when attempting to compile a class of non-OverVoid type.

```
int main() {

  Move<Meta> a;
  Move<OverVoid> b;
  Move<Physical> c;
  // your code goes here
  return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:29:15: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false,    void>'
Move<Physical> c;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but what if _Ty is actually Meta*, it doesnt work, so is there a workaround?

Comment: You can use `std::remove_pointer<_Ty>` to remove the pointer and get the base type.

Comment: `class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<OverVoid, std::remove_pointer<_Ty>::type>::value>::type>`

Answer (score 6):

The simplest thing is just a `static_assert`:

```
template<typename _Ty>
class Move {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<OverVoid, _Ty>::value, 
                  "_Ty must inherit from OverVoid.");
};
```

Note that this allows `OverVoid` to be a private or inaccessible base. If you want to require that it's a public base, you could instead require:

```
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<_Ty*, OverVoid*>::value, 
                  "_Ty must inherit publicly from OverVoid.");
```

Comment: Hello i tried your way but it requires /EHsc flag with msvc++ which i cannot use because fo dev issues but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```
template <typename T>
struct is_overvoid_or_meta
{
     static const bool value = false;
};

template <> struct is_overvoid_or_meta<OverVoid>
{
     static const bool value = true;
};

template <> struct is_overvoid_or_meta<Meta>
{
     static const bool value = true;
};

//Add specialization for all valid types - this allows you to more precisely tell, what types can be used as a template argument for Move
```

And then:

```
template<typename _Ty>
class Move
{
     typedef std::enable_if<is_overvoid_or_meta<_Ty>::value, _Ty>::type Type;
};
```

You will get compile-time error for every type, that is not `OverVoid` or `Meta` (or, more general, for every `T`, for which `is_overvoid_or_meta<T>::value` is `false` - if you will add more of them in the future, you may want to chnge `is_overvoid_or_meta` to more general, like `is_acceptable_by_move` or something):

```
int main()
{
    Move<OverVoid> m1;
    Move<Meta> m2;
    Move<int> m3;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if'
>
> typedef typename std::enable_if::value, _Ty>::type Type;

[Live sample](http://ideone.com/3Ht6IT).

This is very nice solution, because it cannot be tricked - additional template parameter for `Move` can always be specified manually (unless `OverVoid` and `Meta` are not exposed to client).